# What area in complex plane is $\{ z \in \mathbb{C}: |z-1|<|z+1| \}$? Is it open and connected?

Tags: complex-analysis

What area in complex plane is $\{ z \in \mathbb{C}: |z-1|<|z+1| \}$( shade it if possible or describe? Is it open and connected?

I ask to comment my solution:

$|z-1|<|z+1| \Leftrightarrow$ 
$\sqrt{(x-1)^2 +y^2} < \sqrt{(x+1)^2 + y^2} \Leftrightarrow $
$(x-1)^2 < (x+1)^2 | \sqrt{} \Leftrightarrow $
$x-1 < x+1 \Leftrightarrow $
$-1 < 1 ...$
What I can deduce from that? If this is not right can you advice correction?

Comment: $(x-1)^2 < (x+1)^2 \Leftrightarrow  |x-1| < |x+1|$

Comment: If you're familiarity with Mobius transforms isn't sufficient for this exercise, perhaps this 'geometric' intuition will help: what are all complex points which are closer to $1$ than they are to $-1$? To describe the boundary of this domain, consider, which are the points which are equidistant from $\pm 1$?

Comment: $|z-1|$ is the distance in the plane $\mathbb{C}$ from $z$ to the point $1$ in that plane. Similarly for $|z+1|$ and $-1$. Now what geometric locus does your equation describe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not squareroot. Expand both sides, subtract the right one from the left, and you get $-4x<0$. I suppose you can take it from there.

Geometrical interpretation: It is the set of points in $\mathbb{C}$ that is closer to $1$ than to $-1$. That is easily imaginable.

Comment: Is it really $-4x<0$? But this mean that $x>0$(*). So condition is (*) and this means that this area is right-hand-side of $\mathbb{C}$. I like that, because I understood that.

Comment: I have used $(x\pm1)^2=x^2\pm2x+1$. I suppose you can judge on the openness and connectedness yourself, given your knowledge of the area now.

Answer (score 2):

Let's first figure out the boundary (edge) of this region. That is, first let's figure out what $\{ z \in \mathbb{C}: |z-1| = |z+1| \}$ is.

In that case, if $z = x + iy$, the edge is defined by (after a tiny bit of simplification) $(x - 1)^2 = (x + 1)^2$, which is to say, $x = 0$.

So the edge here is the imaginary axis. (vertical line)

Testing a few points should show you that it's the entire right-hand-side of $\mathbb{C}$ (but not including the edge itself, so the region is open and connected, but not bounded).